# Change of boundaries of an integral after using substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration

I saw a solution for $$\int^\infty_0\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}dx$$

They used the substitution $x=1/t$ giving $dx = -dt/t^2$ but why did they flip the boundaries?

$$I = \int^0_\infty\frac{\log 1/t}{1+1/t^2}\left(-dt/t^2\right) $$

Does it have to do something with, that if you flip the integral boundaries you get $-I$?

Comment: They didn't flip the limits, they inverted them.

Answer (score 1):

You flip the boundaries because essentially you also apply the variable change to them.
So, since $x$ was bounded between $x = 0$ and $x = \infty $, you have $$\eqalign{
  & y = {1 \over x} = {1 \over {\mathop {\lim x}\limits_{x \to 0} }} \to \infty   \cr 
  & y = {1 \over x} = {1 \over {\mathop {\lim x}\limits_{x \to \infty } }} \to 0 \cr} $$

Whenever you make a variable change, it would be equally wrong to keep using the older interval in respect to the older variable - that`s why we usually find the "equivalent" interval in terms of the new $y$ in your case.